How to make permanent this manual restart of dhclient?
Jetson Orin AGX Developer Kit with JetPack 6.1 (Ubuntu 22.04 ARM64) boots with accessibility of my local network, but no Internet access due to Temporary failure in name resolution. Here is a log showing how I'm restoring name resolution manually by restarting dhclient:
nick@ubuntu:~$ ping -c 1 yahoo.com
ping: yahoo.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
nick@ubuntu:~$ sudo dhclient -r
nick@ubuntu:~$ sudo dhclient 
nick@ubuntu:~$ ping -c 1 yahoo.com
PING yahoo.com (74.6.143.26) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from media-router-fp74.prod.media.vip.bf1.yahoo.com (74.6.143.26): icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=109 ms

--- yahoo.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 108.810/108.810/108.810/0.000 ms

How can I automate this process, so the Jetson boots with Internet access?
I noticed that after dhclient restart /etc/resolve.conf changes from
nameserver 127.0.0.53

to
nameserver 127.0.0.53
search Home

Do I need to edit a configuration file?

Here is a relevant piece of output from resolvectl, before dhclient restart:
Link 5 (eno1)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 192.168.0.1
       DNS Servers: 192.168.0.1 205.171.3.25

and after dhclient restart:
Link 5 (eno1)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 192.168.0.1
       DNS Servers: 192.168.0.1 205.171.3.25
        DNS Domain: Home

The last line was added. Strangely, all other Ubuntu PCs on my local network are happy with this configuration:
Link 2 (enp5s0)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 205.171.3.25
       DNS Servers: 205.171.3.25

What is the meaning of it? How to add DNS Domain: Home permanently to Jetson configuration?

Entered Home into Search domains in Advanced Network Configuration and the problem disappeared.

If you have this in resolv.conf, it means you're using systemd-resolved. Check the output of resolvectl and compare working and non-working states.

@DanielB I added to my post. The difference is DNS Domain: Home, with a caveat that it is not needed on other systems.

“All other Ubuntu PCs” do not have 192.168.0.1 as a name server. Is it actually a name server? What’s the setup on these PCs? NetworkManager? systemd-networkd? ifup? Maybe a static IP address?

@DanielB 192.168.0.1 is a router IP address. The setup is Ubuntu default with manually set static IP addresses through Ubuntu Settings GUI app. Just a very basic newbie stuff, since I don't have in-depth knowledge about network setup.

Ubuntu 22.04 comes with Network Manager which is by default controlling all network interfaces. If you have only command line interface you can utilize nmcli commands to modify appropriate configs interactively:
https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/networkmanager/edit-connections

Yes, but what do you suggest doing with it?

List network connections using: nmcli connection show. I assume connection is same as interface from your post ("eno1"). Then setup DHCP with NM:
nmcli connection modify eno1 ipv4.method auto .
Then add DNS search suffix:
nmcli connection modify eno1 +ipv4.dns-search "Home"
And finally restart interface to apply:
sudo nmcli connection down eno1
sudo nmcli connection up eno1
